# Comparing arraylist with string element android

Tags: java, android

I am using a listview with an effientadapter.

In my effiicient adapter I initialized and arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<String> stringPosition = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and populate it using where position in arraylist is 1 and 2.

```
stringPosition.add(position);
```

Then in my listview activity in onintemclicklister I check if values stored match the position. but when I click of more than one stored value in arraylist. I get only the last item in the arraylist. how can I

Comparing string with values from arraylist and check if match.

```
for (int i=0;i<EfficientAdapter.stringPosition.size();i++){

        String x = EfficientAdapter.stringPosition.get(i).toString();
        System.out.println("x: " +x);

        if (x.equals(String.valueOf(position)))
            DetailWork.GREEN_OR_BLUE=1;

        else
            DetailWork.GREEN_OR_BLUE=0;

    }
```

how can I solved this issue and is it the best way to compare if some element of listrows is identical to list position. ?

Comment: This is the first time I'm hearing of a EfficientAdapter. What does it do?

Comment: `listView.getSelectedItemPositions()`

Comment: I have to correct my previous comment, getSelectedPositions does not exist. I have ammended in answer.

Comment: @Shark an efficientadapter is just a listAdapter class

Comment: what is the ArrayList of your items that you have passed to your Adapter ?? if they are String  ,so you can use : `x.equals(items.get(position))`

Comment: I suggest you post your `EfficientAdapter` as it contains nonstandard methods, unless you really believe that it's got nothing to do with the solution and/or isn't proprietary, unsharable code.

Answer (score 2):

I can't edit my comment anymore...

for `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` use
    `SparseBooleanArray sba = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();`

for `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` use `int pos = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();`

You can later fetch all these positions from your adapter.